# Is a parent allowed to take items from children over bar/bat mitzvah age but under their jurisdiction

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, children-parenting, gezel-stealing, contemporary-halacha

According to Halacha, is a parent allowed to confiscate property from their children if that child is over bar/bat mitzvah age but the age they would be under the parent’s jurisdiction? So is it stealing if a parent takes property earned and owned by their 14 year old that lives with them?

Comment: This would apply only where parents must support their children up to 18 - otherwise they can just charge them rent!

Comment: It is also about exercising authority. Can they take an item as a reasonable punishment or would that be stealing? What rules here: halacha or civil law of the country about the age of majority?

Comment: The din seems to imply the obligation to support is only up to the age of six

Comment: @sam could be local law/custom binds here and would force support to 18. Another implication of this is that you probably can't consider your children's support as tzedaka/maaser since you have to do it either way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems from the gemara in [Bava Metzia 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.12b.2?lang=bi), and the Shulchan Aruch [CM 270:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.270.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that, whether the son/daughter is a gadol (13/12) or a katan, if they are being supported, their things belong to the father (except gifts possibly).

Text of Shulchan Aruch :

> מציאת בנו ובתו הסמוכים על שולחנו אע"פ שהם גדולים ומציאת בתוהנערה אע"פ
> שאינה סומכת על שולחנו ומציאת עבדו ושפחתו הכנענים ומציאת אשתו הרי אלו
> שלו ד(וה"ה אם הרויחו בסחורה או במלאכה (ב"י ססי' קע"ז בשם עיטור) אבל אם
> מת אינו מוריש מלאכת בן אחד לשאר ורשיו)

Comment: I +1'd but not the SA you quote is regarding found objects. Regarding a child over 12/13 not supported by their parents, see [CM 235:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.235.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that their possessions are theirs